# Addressable Latch IC to control single output

Tags: integrated-circuit, led-driver

I am trying to implement a circuit using simple addressable ICs. The one I tried was WS2811 RGB Led Driver (Neopixel). But my requirement is not that complex. In my case there is only one LED needs to be driven by an IC instead of 3 in WS2811.

Also I require little more current per LEDs.

So Is there is any better addressable Latch ICs option for this SINGLE LED with higher current works same as Ws2811.

Adding little more details which I missed at first.

There are 50, 20watt leds in string which I need to address individually. The difference with pixel strings is, only single color LED I require. Thats why I thought about a simple addressable IC than WS2811 with 3 output (RGB)

Comment: Why do you need it to be addressable if there is only one? And how much current do you need?

Comment: Sorry I missed the point.. There are 50 leds in string same as neopixel, but no RGB led, thats the difference.. So I can address any of the 50 Leds in string. I am using a 20watt led. (I updated the question as well)

Comment: How much currrent do you need? If the WS2811 is otherwise suitable, can you parallel its 3 outputs for more current, or can you use each channel to drive a separate LED?

Comment: @polwel Each of the LEDs require 20watt. The parallel idea seems to be great, but does it really recommended??  Sorry I am only a beginner in electronics..

Comment: You'll need to tell us how much *current* (amps) you need, or provide us with a datasheet if you are unsure.

Comment: @polwel Sorry its a 12v (2A) led

Comment: Ouch, so it is 1kW in total? (For comparison, your WS2811 does <20mA per channel, you need 2000mA.) A linear regulator like the one you suggested will not do at this power level. Switching drivers are nowhere near as simple to use than the IC you mentioned. I suggest you start looking for driver *modules* (not ICs), and then worry about the control signal later.

Comment: Got you.. Thanks a lot